# Formatting numeric values on Android that don't use western digits

Tags: java, android, internationalization

On iOS there's a handy function on NSNumber

```
localizedStringWithStyle:
```

Which will format a numeric value into a string using digits appropriate to that region (possibly Western, possible Arabic, etc).

I assume in Java on Android a NumberFormat object (or similar) could be configured to do this but I'm not sure how.

So my question.  In Android how to you format a number in locale specific digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate the [`NumberFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) object, you call it like this:

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

You can pick from the [list of static `Locale`s](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) or call [`NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getAvailableLocales%28%29) to search for a locale which matches your desired output.

Comment: Or use Locale.getDefault() to use the current one.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n;
String.format("%d", n);
```

That's all. `String.format` uses the user's locale by default. You can request a particular locale by passing it as the first argument (i.e. before the format string).